# Map function in react (err: TypeError: e.map is not a function)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, map-function

I want to render items from props, I can do it with initial state, but not with response from server. My render function :

```
 const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <div >
          {data.map((item, index) =>
              <div key={index} className="row">
                  <span data = { data } className="number col-4 col-md-8">{item._id}</span>
                  <span data = { data } className="date col-4 col-md-2">{item.date}</span>
                  <span data = { data }  className="tag col-4 col-md-2">{item.tag}</span>
                  <div className="col-md-12 ">
                    {item.text}
                  </div>                
              </div>
          )}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I get this mistake :

> TypeError: e.map is not a function

response :  Object {data: Array(12), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}

Comment: Where's your call to the server? Where is `e.map` in your code?

Comment: Can you show how are you updating your data prop from the response? It looks like data becomes undefined, so I think you are overriding something, but I cannot tell until I see the code.

Answer (score 3):

Had to change parent component change this:

```
  this.setState({
    data: response
  })
```

to

```
  this.setState({
    data: response.data
  })
```

I've tried to reach the data from the child component, but it din't work (probably because of the map function)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your response is just the raw response. If you're using fetch, this is what the promise chain should look like:

```
fetch(fromMySource).then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => doSomething(data));
```

It looks like you might be trying to use resp directly which would make your data array look like the response object you posted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these words to your map function,
Because you need check if the array was existed then execute map function

```
const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <div >
          {data && data.length && data.map((item, index) =>
              <div key={index} className="row">
                  <span data = { data } className="number col-4 col-md-8">{item._id}</span>
                  <span data = { data } className="date col-4 col-md-2">{item.date}</span>
                  <span data = { data }  className="tag col-4 col-md-2">{item.tag}</span>
                  <div className="col-md-12 ">
                    {item.text}
                  </div>                
              </div>
          )}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: looks like it renders while response doesn't exist yet, and doesn't rerenders after..

Answer (score 0):

You can use default value of `data`, when response is pending. In this time `data` is not defined

```
const { data = [] } = this.props;
```

Or use condition in  jsx:

```
render() {
   if (!data || !data.length) return null;
   ...
}
```