# TypeError: E.map is not a function reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using react js, to create a react app, but got this error, **TypeError: E.map is not a function**, it's working well, but when I'm trying to deploy my website it says that error.

this is code.

```
 <ul className="products">
      {products.map((product) => (
        <li key={product._id}>
          <div className="product">
            <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}>
              <img
                className="product-image"
                src={product.image}
                alt="product"
              />
            </Link>
            <div className="product-name">
              <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}>{product.name}</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="product-brand">{product.brand}</div>
            
            <div className="product-rating">
              <Rating
                value={product.rating}
                text={product.numReviews + ' reviews'}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

please help to figer out it,
thank you.

Comment: Can you post any screenshot of the error? I can't find `E.map` in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map function in react (err: TypeError: e.map is not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787301/map-function-in-react-err-typeerror-e-map-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I can't post an image from here I don't know!

Comment: @MurtazaHassani why?

Answer (score -1):

Check is `products` value an Array, then map on them

You can do something like this

```
render() {
    if (!Array.isArray(products)) return null
    ... heree your code
}
```

except null, you can return something like `Products not founds`

or in initializing of `products` you can give a default value

`const { products = [] } = props`

but in this case, if products come `null` you will get the same error

Comment: Hey, thanks for your replying, i tried but get an error that says product not defined,

Comment: Can you please send the whole file?
You can put it in codesanbox for example and put a link here

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-code-shbvh?file=/src/App.js this is that code that i get error

Comment: Can you try to update your code like this?

```const { products = [], loading, error } = productList;```

or like this 

```(products || []).map(product => ...```